# JSON at position 4 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, http, ionic3, httpmodule, angular-httpclient

I got some issues to connect to my Web Service with json.
I can connect, but the problem come's when i need to convert the Json to html to read and work with him.
I read and i tried to resolve the issue changing the headers, cause i got "text/html" and i think the correct form is "application/json" in the content-type, but i don't know how to do it.
I post the code, thanks.

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {DbProvider} from '../../providers/db/db';
import { UserPage } from '../user/user';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, ResponseType } from '@angular/http';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

export class HomePage {
  public db : DbProvider;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public menu: MenuController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public http: Http,
    public https: HttpClient) {
  }
  ejercicios: any[];
  ejercicio : any;

        GetJson(){
        return this.https.get('http://localhost:55531/postData.aspx/getEjercicioss'
                ).subscribe(data => {
              this.ejercicios = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
         console.log(this.ejercicios);
            }, err => {

              console.log(err);
            });
     }
```

home.html

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="GetJson($event)" ></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let ejercicio of ejercicios">
     <h2>{{ejercicio}} </h2> 
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:55531/postData.aspx/getEjercicioss", ok: false, …}error: error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:62956:51)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794)
    at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27648)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)text: "
↵
↵<!DOCTYPE html>
↵
↵<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
↵<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
↵
↵</title></head>
↵<body>
↵    <form method="post" action="./getEjercicioss" id="form1">
↵<div class="aspNetHidden">
↵<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="EX/ydFzdOvrh/wJJPw/k6+GazbjGG2/Dwo2xbT4Hsp/pkl99AUP52DZ6+H4lWTQHblIBu3gHfqFGpVbL0RsTsy+i2EPqxOtS/QsOPQHG6Xc=" />
↵</div>
↵
↵<div class="aspNetHidden">
↵
↵   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="981629C3" />
↵</div>
↵        <div>
↵        </div>
↵    </form>
↵</body>
↵</html>
↵"__proto__: Objectheaders: HttpHeaderslazyInit: ƒ ()lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}__proto__: Objectmessage: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:55531/postData.aspx/getEjercicioss"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:55531/postData.aspx/getEjercicioss"__proto__: HttpResponseBaseconstructor: ƒ HttpErrorResponse(init)__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Why do you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`? I looks like you get HTML (not JSON) and don't need JSON either... so why at all involve JSON?

Comment: Can you post an example of your JSON object (lifted from browser network response would be best)

Comment: If I change this JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))  for  this.ejercicio = data; I got the same issue, but it doesn't appear like an error. And tomorrow i'll post some example of my Json object.

Comment: Here you got the WebMethod:         public static List<Work> getEjercicioss()
        {
            List<Work> list = new List<Work>();
            CtrlEjercicio c = new CtrlEjercicio();
            String IdL = "ESP";
            try
            {

                list = c.GetAll(IdL);
                return list;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return list;
            }
        } and the